# Android Studio Error: 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: android, android-studio

I am getting this error after adding a libriaes project while try to run the application.

```
Android Studio version : 1.2.1.1
```

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.
>
> > com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
> >     'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with
> >     non-zero exit value 2

Comment: compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar']) add this line in your gradle if not exist

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've got this error when I had duplicates of libraries. For example if some module uses the same library that you are adding to the project this error might occur. Try to find if there are any duplicates in your app.

**EDIT**

Yes correct , I have two same library in my module indirectly.
In my main project I am using `android.support.v4.app` jar and a android library project, this library project also containing same jar `android.support.v4.app` file which was already have in my main project, so simply I was deleted `android.support.v4.app` from my main project, finally this solution will working fine.