# Exception Failed for task

Tags: android, android-fragments, google-maps-api-3

in my android project whenever I import Map Activity.. compiles gives me some error like:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

how can I fixed it??
my Module is:

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
}
```

Comment: have u sync your gradle?

Comment: Please try with the current version of play services. compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0'

Comment: please add full gradle file

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Android Studio Error: 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0\_75\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938101/android-studio-error-command-c-program-files-java-jdk1-7-0-75-bin-java-exe)

Answer (score -1):

> I also had same issue, i just replaced my 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.4.0' with 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.4.0' bcs i was implementing google maps in my project, for yours individual need check [here](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup), i hope it would work :)

or you still wanna use whole library at once so you need to enable multidex. here is the steps:

1: Add multidex dependency in Module:app

```
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
```

2: then enable mutidex in Module:app file in defaultConfig section like this

```
defaultConfig {
    ...
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

3: add below line in Manifest in application section like this

```
<application
    android:name="android.support.multidex.MultiDexApplication"
    ...
    ...
```

4: Rebuild project.

Happy Coding :)