# Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Tags: java, android, dex

I have got an error on

> Execution failed for task ':dexRelease'.
>   com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_79\bin\java.exe'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

Here is my build.gradle
It will be helpful if you solve this problem.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.3.0'
    }
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

    repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven {
        url "https://repository-achartengine.forge.cloudbees.com/snapshot/"
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile('com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.apache.httpcomponents'
        exclude group: 'xpp3'
        exclude group: 'junit'
        exclude group: 'com.google.android'
    }
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.2.0'
    compile 'org.achartengine:achartengine:1.1.0'
    compile 'ch.acra:acra:4.6.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:8.3.0'
    compile 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-adsense:v1.4-rev29-1.19.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.1'
    compile 'net.sf.opencsv:opencsv:2.3'
    compile 'com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:1.3.9'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-identity:8.3.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.3.0'
}

android {

    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

// lintOptions {
//     checkReleaseBuilds false
//     abortOnError false
// }


signingConfigs {
    release {
        storeFile file("andlytics-release-key.keystore")
    }
}

buildTypes {
    release {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.release
    }
}

sourceSets {
    main {
        manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        java.srcDirs = ['src']
        resources.srcDirs = ['src']
        aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
        renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
        res.srcDirs = ['res']
        assets.srcDirs = ['assets']
    }

    // Move the build types to build-types/<type>
    // For instance, build-types/debug/java, build-             types/debug/AndroidManifest.xml, ...
    // This moves them out of them default location under src/<type>/...       which would
    // conflict with src/ being used by the main source set.
    // Adding new build types or product flavors should be accompanied
    // by a similar customization.
        debug.setRoot('build-types/debug')
        release.setRoot('build-types/release')
    }
}

if (project.hasProperty('storePassword')
        && project.hasProperty('keyAlias')
        && project.hasProperty('keyPassword')) {
    android.signingConfigs.release.storePassword = storePassword
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyAlias = keyAlias
    android.signingConfigs.release.keyPassword = keyPassword
}
```

Comment: What have your tried so far to find the reason? e.g. run it in debug mode, check for missed dependencies, something like that.

Comment: My other source code are running well but still the above one doesn't work.

Comment: Have you run already the build in debug mode? There should be more information at which step it is failing.

Comment: may be this will help you ..check this[ link ]and try to find duplicate library which conflict to your project(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938101/android-studio-error-command-c-program-files-java-jdk1-7-0-75-bin-java-exe)